# How do I prove what the limit of a function is using the definition of a limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

Let's say I had to prove the $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}(x^2-3x+4) = 2$. I know that I have to show that for any $k \gt 0$, there exists an $f(k) \gt 0$ such that if $0 \lt |x-2| \lt f(k)$, $|(x^2-3x+4)-2| \lt k$.

I already to $|(x^2 - 3x + 4) - 2|$ to $|x-1|\cdot|x-2|$, but where do I go from here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [the answers to this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696680/how-do-i-solve-delta-epsilon-proofs-for-quadratic-equations) or [this pdf](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~yosenl/math/epsilon-delta.pdf).

Comment: $|x-1|\leq(|x-2|+1)$, so $|x-1||x-2)\leq(f(k)+1)f(k)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does there exist an epsilon-delta proof of the limit for all polynomials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1485468/does-there-exist-an-epsilon-delta-proof-of-the-limit-for-all-polynomials)